# I want to create new page on a button click in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to send GET, POST request to server to get a response. how to do that in Wordpress?

Comment: You want to automatically create a new page?  What will the page be named?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
<a href="<?php echo admin_url('post-new.php?post_type=page');?>">
Create new page</a>
```

You can place this code whereever you want in your theme. To give the link button UI, you can use any CSS button class of your theme.
F.e.

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="<?php echo admin_url('post-new.php?post_type=page');?>">
    Create new page</a>
```

Comment: Which button? You need to add more details to your question

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\awesomeTheme\index.php on line 27

Comment: This just links them to the dashboard but doesn't create a new page automatically.

Comment: now i need to send a post call to a server to get response.. please help .. what is the method for that?